# Ubuntu 14.04.3 Installation Issues

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

hoping to get some help here... I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server on an old Lenovo/IBM machine that I have, and have had it up & running successfully for quite some time. My daughter needs a workstation for homework now, though, so I wanted to completely wipe this drive & do a fresh install of 14.04.3 Desktop. I booted the Live CD with minimal issues, but it hangs on the purple Ubuntu screen & doesn't seem to be doing anything. I never get to the point of it even asking me for any input. I read that pushing Alt+F2 would give some kind of verbose output, so here's what I'm seeing when I do that:

```
[82117.099733] ata2.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:fc/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0 pio 65536 in
[82117.099733]          res 58/00:02:00:00:60/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x6 (timeout)
[82117.106728] ata2.00: status: {DRDY DRQ }
[82160.104046] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
```

This has been showing up repeatedly, through several attempts to install. My research online has lead me to believe that this could be an HDD issue? I swapped another drive into the machine just to test, and the same errors showed up. It seems like it could also be a BIOS issue, and I've played with a few of those settings as well. A few of the other errors I've seen at different time while trying to install are as follows:

```
[82416.297068] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 334224
MP-BIOS bug: 8254 timer not connected to IO-APIC
ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219
```

The latter two show up at the very beginning of the Ubuntu boot process... I also see intermittent messages about various tasks being blocked:

> INFO: task *** blocked for more than 120 seconds.

After several attempts, I have now reached a point (by letting it run overnight to see what happens) where I actually seem to have a grub command line... any advice? Can someone help me finish this installation?

Comment: No one has any ideas? Anyone need more information or anything?